# Fluid mechanics control volume does not have constant mass

Tags: fluid-dynamics

When deriving the net force acting on a fluid in the Eulerian formulation, my course takes $\vec F =\dfrac{d(m\vec V)}{dt}$, then applies a Lagrangian CV formulation.  This makes sense, as we are tracking a constant mass of fluid, and Newton's Second Law requires that mass be constant.

But then, when switching to the Eulerian volume which does not track a constant mass, we use the same F=dP/dt definition, and I do not see why that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

The Conservation of Momentum Equation for a fluid is as follows:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left[ \int_\text{CV} \rho \vec{u} \, dv \right] + \int_\text{CS} \rho \vec{u} (\vec{u} \cdot \vec{n}) \, dA = \sum \vec{F} $$
where $\rho$ is fluid density, $\vec{u}$ is the fluid velocity vector, $\vec{n}$ is the unit normal vector at the Control Surface.
Drawing a control volume and its surface boundary shows that the first term is the unsteady term, which accounts for the addition/removal of specific momentum $\rho \vec{u}$ within the CV, whereas the second term accounts for the specific momentum flux through the CS boundary, and the final term is the sum of outside forces acting on this control volume, whether they be on the CS or body forces within the CV.

Note: we can use $\rho$ instead of $m$ because the volume is fixed, and as a result, using specific momentum $\rho \vec{u}$ is just a proportion of $m \vec{u}$.

Does this address your question?